# Open CMD in the Visual Studio Code terminal

Tags: cmd, visual-studio-code

Whenever I open the terminal in Visual Studio Code, I get a bash shell. I want to add CMD as a second shell. To do that, I went through the VS Code documentation and found this command:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>

But it only opens a second bash shell. Is there a shortcut for opening CMD in the integrated terminal, rather than opening it in an external console?

[image: Screengrab showing console window in VSCode]

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49034689) will help

Answer (score 31):

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> to open the command palette.
2. Type **'profile'** in the searcher.
3. Select **'Terminal: Select Default Profile'**.
4. Select **'Command Prompt'**
5. The next time you try to open the terminal you should see **'CMD'** instead of **'PowerShell'**.

Comment: This option no longer exists in vs code 1.59

Answer (score 15):

If you want to always open cmd, you can use the settings to configure that.

From the [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_windows):

> Correctly configuring your shell on Windows is a matter of locating the right executable and updating the setting.
> Below are a list of common shell executables and their default locations:

```
// Command Prompt
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe"
// PowerShell
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe"
// Git Bash
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\git-cmd.exe",
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": [
  "--command=usr/bin/bash.exe",
  "-l",
  "-i"
]
// Bash on Ubuntu (on Windows)
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\bash.exe"
```

If you want to only sometimes open cmd, you may be able to simply open a new bash terminal and then run `cmd` in it.

If you use both frequently, you may want to use an extension like [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Tyriar.shell-launcher) or [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=remcoros.startanyshell) which allow you to pick your terminal when you launch it.

Keybindings:

```
  [{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+t",
    "command": "shellLauncher.launch"
  }]
```

Settings:

```
  {
    "shellLauncher.shells.windows": [
      {
        "shell": "bash",
        "args": [],
        "label": "bash"
      }, {
        "shell": "cmd",
        "args": [],
        "label": "cmd"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: when I put this code in setting JSON file, a message show me `unknown configuration setting`

Answer (score 8):

Add this on user setting
**Note: paste at top**

```
{

   "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "cmd.exe"
    // other settings...

}
```

Answer (score 8):

I don't know why anyone else hasn't mentioned it yet, but here's the simplest way to open CMD in VSCode.

Just type CMD in the terminal and hit enter.

Answer (score 5):

You can change your current terminal to whatever you need (or have).

[image]

Or you can use **Ctrl + Shift + P** to open the Command Palette and type *Terminal Profile*, then change the default profile.

[image]

[image]

This will change your startup terminal. If you start a new one, the default terminal will always open.

Comment: This answer is consistent with differentiating hard drive letter 

Answer (score 3):

Just open the terminal and enter the link to your cmd application e.g
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe

Answer (score 1):

Opening the cmd terminal from VSCode

**Ctrl** + **Shift** + **C**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open another CMD terminal, from the VS Code terminal or any other terminal, use

```
@start run cmd .
```

or when you want to go on dir above and open cmd there:

```
cd .. & @start cmd .
```

Comment: To open the VS Code terminal,
~ + SHIFT + CTRL