# Cannot get all shells configured in VSCode for Shell Launcher

Tags: visual-studio-code

I followed the instructions from [How to add multiple terminal in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43427631/how-to-add-multiple-terminal-in-vs-code)

When I type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> (my custom shortcut) only Powershell and Git Bash are listed whereas cmd and wsl not there, why are they missing ?

[image]

Comment: Please read [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43427631/how-to-add-multiple-terminal-in-vs-code/50890703#50890703](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43427631/how-to-add-multiple-terminal-in-vs-code/50890703#50890703) for complete solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> **You use the incorrect paths in extension settings!**
>
> You can find the necessary paths by running the following commands in the windows console (cmd):

`where cmd` (for cmd)

`where powershell` (for PowerShell)

`where bash` (for Git bash, WSL Bash)

Here is one of the possible options for a 64 bit windows:

```
"shellLauncher.shells.windows": [
    {
      "shell": "C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\cmd.exe",
      "label": "cmd"
    },
    {
      "shell": "C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe",
      "label": "PowerShell"
    },
    {
      "shell": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe",
      "label": "Git bash"
    },
    {
      "shell": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\bash.exe",
      "label": "WSL Bash"
    }
]
```

> Then you can select the one you need with via a shortcut:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+alt+s",
    "command": "shellLauncher.launch"
}
```

> After that you can select one in the list in the terminal panel.

Comment: Thanks, what was my error exactly, can't see it clearly ?

Comment: PowerShell - default shell for Windows, so it worked. Git was given right path. For WSL Bash and cmd were wrong paths specified. Sysnative (as I understand) is only an example, instead of which you need to specify the path for a particular system. Therefore it seems to me in "terminal.integrated.shell.windows" it is better to specify correct path to shell that you want to use by default.