# Port 8081 is redirected to http://localhost:8082/

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

My Port is 8081, but when running using npm run dev, It is redirected to http://localhost:8082/. Due to this, I am facing issue pointing to other URLs. I want localhost to be 8081. Any idea?

Comment: It sounds like you already have something running on port 8081.

Comment: You can kill the proccess that runs on the port (according to your OS).

Comment: I am using npm. How to check it in vs code and kill it?

Answer (score 1):

it look like you have another process running on port 8081
to list process running on a specific port you can do

**on windows**

the command to identify the process running on a specific port is

```
netstat -aon | find /i "listening"
```

you can kill the process with

```
taskkill /f /pid 1234
```

**on linux**

```
sudo lsof -n -i :8081 | grep LISTEN
```

it will show you something with columns

```
COMMAND  PID        USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
```

you can kill the process with

```
kill -9 pid
```

the second ones is the pid if you don't want this running process you can stop or kill it

Comment: I am using npm. How to check it in vs code and kill it?

Comment: ok  you are on a windows system or a linux system ?

Comment: windows systems

Comment: ok so with vs code you can open a command prompt with this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46107955/open-cmd-in-the-visual-studio-code-terminal and use `netstat -aon | find /i "listening"`to identify the running process

Comment: i edit my reply with windows information